# Error while writing to external storage

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-external-storage

I am writing a simple app that takes a photo, video or choose an existing photo/video.

I am writing the code for the first two options, but when I run it, it fails to create the directory for some reason. (I have correct permission in the manifest: ANDROID.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) Anyone have an idea why this code fails to create the directory (Log.e(TAG,"Failer to create directory");)
The file should be saved in storage/sdcard/Pictures/nameOfTheApp...
but instead when I log it: log: D/AppCompatActivity﹕ /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/nameOfTheApp 
its in a different place.
this is the my code here:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
public static final int TAKE_PHOTO_REQUEST = 0;
public static final int TAKE_VIDEO_REQUEST = 1;
public static final int PICK_PHOTO_REQUEST = 2;
public static final int PICK_VIDEO_REQUEST = 3;

public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 4;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 5;

// media path as Uri (Uniform resource unifier) unify system resorses
protected Uri mMediaUri;

protected DialogInterface.OnClickListener mDialogListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        switch (which){
            case 0:  //Take picture
                Intent takePhotoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                mMediaUri = getOutputMediaFileUrl(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
                if(mMediaUri == null){
                    // display an error
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,getString(R.string.error_external_storage),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                takePhotoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,mMediaUri);
                startActivityForResult(takePhotoIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_REQUEST);
                break;
            case 1:
                break; //Take video
            case 2:
                break; //Choose picture
            case 3:
                break; //Choose video
        }
    }

    private Uri getOutputMediaFileUrl(int mediaType) {
        if(isExternalStoreageAvailable()){
            //get URI

            // 1. Get the external storage directory
            String appName = MainActivity.this.getString(R.string.app_name);
            File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                                        appName);
            // 2. Create our subdirectory
            if(! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
                //creates directory. IF fails returns false
                if(! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                    Log.e(TAG,"Failer to create directory");
                    return null;
                };
            }
            // 3. Create a file name
            // 4. Create the file
            File mediaFile;
            Date now = new Date();
            String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.UK).format(now);
            String path = mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator;
            if(mediaType == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
                mediaFile = new File(path + "IMG_" + timestamp + ".jpg");
            }else if (mediaType == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO){
                mediaFile = new File(path + "VID_" + timestamp + ".mp4");
            }else{
                return null;
            }

            // 5. Return the file's uri
            Log.d(TAG,"File: " + Uri.fromFile(mediaFile));
            return Uri.fromFile(mediaFile);
        }else{
            return null;
        }

    }

    private boolean isExternalStoreageAvailable(){
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if(state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
};
```

Log:

```
05-29 10:30:02.487  23529-23529/koemdzhiev.com.blinkmessage I/art﹕ Late-   enabling -Xcheck:jni
05-29 10:30:03.071  23529-23529/koemdzhiev.com.blinkmessage   I/AppCompatActivity﹕ MariyaM
05-29 10:30:03.121  23529-23574/koemdzhiev.com.blinkmessage D/OpenGLRenderer﹕  Render dirty regions requested: true
05-29 10:30:03.133  23529-23529/koemdzhiev.com.blinkmessage D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
05-29 10:30:03.213  23529-23574/koemdzhiev.com.blinkmessage I/Adreno-EGL﹕   <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:   AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.1.C2.05.00.00.046.002_msm8974_LA.BF.1.1.1.C2__release_A U ()
OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.00
Build Date: 01/06/15 Tue
Local Branch: mybranch6793908
Remote Branch: quic/LA.BF.1.1.1.c2
Local Patches: NONE
Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.1.C2.05.00.00.046.002 +  NOTHING
05-29 10:30:03.216  23529-23574/koemdzhiev.com.blinkmessage I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
05-29 10:30:03.238  23529-23574/koemdzhiev.com.blinkmessage D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
05-29 10:30:03.391  23529-23529/koemdzhiev.com.blinkmessage I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@37271f15 time:14614103
05-29 10:30:06.647  23529-23539/koemdzhiev.com.blinkmessage W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 40.361ms
05-29 10:30:08.772  23529-23529/koemdzhiev.com.blinkmessage E/AppCompatActivity﹕ Failer to create directory
05-29 10:30:09.069  23529-23574/koemdzhiev.com.blinkmessage V/RenderScript﹕ Application requested CPU execution
05-29 10:30:09.248  23529-23574/koemdzhiev.com.blinkmessage V/RenderScript﹕ 0xafa7d000 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4
05-29 10:30:21.531  23529-23529/koemdzhiev.com.blinkmessage I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@37271f15 time:14632243
05-29 10:32:05.225  23529-23529/koemdzhiev.com.blinkmessage I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@37271f15 time:14735937
05-29 10:32:39.136  23529-23529/koemdzhiev.com.blinkmessage E/AppCompatActivity﹕ Failer to create directory
05-29 10:41:31.324  23529-23539/koemdzhiev.com.blinkmessage W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 5.421ms
```

Comment: post your error log as well

Comment: It's not an actual error, the code jumps right into the Log.d statement that ways that it fails to create the directory. However, I am going to put the whole log as well. Thanks :)

Comment: Log the value of "mediaStorageDir" after it is set. What does your device think that directory is?

Comment: Ok I logged it (Log.d(TAG,mediaStorageDir + "");) log: D/AppCompatActivity﹕ /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Blink Message 

(Blink Message is the name of the app :))

Comment: If you are using Emulator then check for the memory available. Otherwise add more memory.

Comment: I am using a physical device, not an Emulator. It was plenty of memory available :)

Comment: `ANDROID.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)`. Never heard of such a permission. SHow waht you have in manifest file please.

Comment: regarding the permission it is here in this guide that I was following: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html

Comment: I will not look there. You were asked to show what you have written in manifest file. So please do.

Comment: This is what I have in my manifest: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true"/>

Comment: Well why that one in capitals? That will not work. Make -ANDROID.PERMISSION- lowercase as the others.

Comment: Nope, I did it in lower case letters as you suggested, it fails again:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.write_external_storage"/>

Comment: My god....`write_external_storage"` should be capitals! Look at your other permissions.

Comment: Thank you so much, greenapps! That solved the problem! I did not realise that I should be so strict about the caps (there was no compiler error). I am a beginner as you already know and I really appreciate your time and effort helping me! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `ANDROID.PERMISSION` lowercase as the others.